# Construction of a function on a fat (generalized) cantor set with specific conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For every $\epsilon>0$ let $F_\epsilon$ is a closed set on $[0,1]$ s.t. $mF_\epsilon\geq1-\epsilon$, for which I have constructed a fat cantor set with measure $1-\frac{a}{1-2a}$, where interval of the length $a^n$ is removed from remaining $2^{n-1}$ subintervals of $[0,1]$ at the $n$-th step, and $\frac{a}{1-2a}$ is sum of the removals for which  $\frac{a}{1-2a}\leq \epsilon$.

Now using the set above, for every $\epsilon>0$, I want to construct a function $f_\epsilon(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that

(1) $f_\epsilon(x)$ is strictly increasing

(2) $f_\epsilon(x)$ is absolutely continuous

(3) $f^{'}_\epsilon(x)=0$ on a set $F_\epsilon$ with $mF_\epsilon\geq1-\epsilon$.

For doing so, I constructed the function $f_\epsilon(x)=m(F_\epsilon\cap[0,x])$. It is strictly increasing. I am not able to show that conditions (2) and (3) satisfies. Since it must be increasing, I wonder how its derivative can be 0! Maybe the function I have constructed is not correct.

I sincerely appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the construction of the Cantor staircase work the same on fat Cantor sets?

Comment: @G.S. How about derivative of this function to be zero? Cantor staircase is absolutely continuous.

Comment: Cantor staircase is uniformly continuous but non absolutely continuous. Its derivative is almost everywhere zero. Point is that it is a BV function so you really talk about of distributional derivative which is made up of three pieces: $D^a u$ which is the part absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure, $D^ju$ which is the jump part and is non zero roughly at discountinuity points of the functions and $D^c u$ which is the remaining part and called the cantorian derivative. Cantor staircase distributional derivative has only this cantorian part.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: the only non-zero part of the Cantor staircase's derivative is the Cantorian part. It has no $D^j$ but it has a $D^a$ part which is zero a.e.

Comment: @G.S. Thanks a lot for helping me on solving the problem. I was wrong that cantor staircase function is absolutely continuous, yes it's not. Also it's derivative is zero and it's increasing. But, it does not work for this problem as I need a function to be A.C.